# Do you have to use a skill from the KRB when a character doesn't have it or should you use a generic characteristic?

Tags: skills, call-of-cthulhu-7e

Let's say a player wants to use a sword to fight an enemy in Call of Cthulhu 7e but didn't pick that specific skill for the character, should you as a keeper make the player roll a sword skill (20%) from the Keeper Rulebook (p. 64) against a difficulty of the base 20% (with penalty?) or should the player make a general DEX role with penalty die?

Basically, should you pick a skill on character creation to be able to use it or can you use any skill with base difficulty if your character doesn't have it?

Answer (score 3):

Not having a skill is synonym of just having the base percentage.
Even if you do not have knowledge/experience using a sword you can just swing it around (albeit clumsily) and hit hard on someone. On the contrary, it is very unlikely that someone would be able to solve a hard mathematical problem without previous knowledge/experience (and hence, that sort of skills normally have 1% base).

**JFYI:** There is an optional rule: "Transferable skill benefit" that makes a lot of sense in my view. It allows you to take into account the fact that some skills are similar enough to be at least marginally helpful (i.e. Use your Portuguese to try to read a book in Spanish).

Comment: Thank you so much. So if I get it right, it would indeed be a normal roll against 20%.